# Why is making a tuple from a generator expression slower than making one from a list comprehension?

Tags: python-3.x, performance

(This question is based on a now deleted tweet)

I ran the following with both Python3.9 and Python3.10:

```py
$ python -m timeit 'tuple([-x for x in range(1000)])'
10000 loops, best of 5: 35.7 usec per loop
$ python -m timeit 'tuple(-x for x in range(1000))'
5000 loops, best of 5: 45.7 usec per loop
```

Surprisingly, the version where an extra object is constructed (the list) is faster. Why is this the case? If this is indeed faster, why does the tuple constructor not just instantiate a list under the hood?

Note: I also timed these for length 10 and length 1 million tuples, and the version with the list is always faster.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this one:

```
python -m timeit 'list(-x for x in range(1000))'
```

I predict you'll find it takes about the same time as your:

```
python -m timeit 'tuple(-x for x in range(1000))'
```

and that

```
python -m timeit 'list([-x for x in range(1000)])'
```

would again restore the "lost" speed.

This is because list versus tuple actually has nothing to do with it. It's instead that `tuple()` and `list()` are just function calls to Python, and may invoke anything whatsoever (by default, those names are bound to built-in functions, but the user may rebind them to anything).

But `[expression for vrb in ...]` is dedicated *syntax*, whose meaning user code cannot change. Python knows at compile-time that it's building a list, and generates special code to exploit that. That code never calls `list()` at all, but instead builds the list directly itself, one element at a time. No generator expression is actually constructed, and there's no overhead either for yielding one element at a time from a generator expression.

Build simple functions containing these kinds of expressions and use `dis.dis()` to show the generated byte code. The code is very different :-)

Comment: Thank you for the explanation! I had thought the function call couldn't be the important part since the gap seemed to scale with the size, but not needing to yield makes perfect sense.